# Angular $http Inceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, interceptor

My understanding were that when I make an `$http.post()` Like below code, then my interceptor should prehandle the incomming data and response to it's error/success method. But when I do `$q.reject(response.data);` (and I've checked that the data are there). Then in my error I'd get those data that I reject with. But i don't `data` in the `.error` is null

**Code:**
`LTS` is my module

**Http request**

```
$http.post("/overview", searchCriterias).success(function(data) {
                console.log('InboundController : success in http call');
                $scope.searchState = "result";
                $scope.result = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('InboundController : error in http call');
                $scope.searchState = "error";
                console.log(data);
                if (data.errorMessage)
                    $scope.result = data.errorMessage;
                else
                    $scope.result = data;
            });
```

**Interceptor**

```
LTS.factory('defaultHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
        response: function(response) {
            // do something on success
//            console.log(response.headers());
            if (response.headers()['content-type'].indexOf("application/json;charset=UTF-8") > -1) {
//                 Validate response, if not ok reject
                var dataPresent = response.data;
                if (dataPresent && dataPresent.state && dataPresent.state !== "OK") {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                } else {
                    return response.data;
                }
            }
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
            // do something on error
            console.log('defaultHttpInterceptor : http error');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
LTS.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('defaultHttpInterceptor');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh found out that `$q.reject(response)` already unpacks the .data to the error handler.
So my `.error` got null because the `response.data` did not have a `.data` (`response.data.data`) attribute (of cause).

I'll let it stand for future references.